# checking key using 'for in' returns undefined

Tags: javascript, object

I'm checking to see if a key exists in an object from another object so I am doing something like this:

```
var user = {
  'email' : 'dothis',
  'derp' : 'yo'
};
```

And then I'm checking to see if it exists within this:

```
var cookies = {
  'email':'hello@gmail.com'
}
```

I'm checking like this:

```
for(var key in cookies) {
  if(user[key]){
   // do this
  }
}
```

But no matter what I do it will return undefined. However it does work when I just do:

```
user['email'];
```

Which is correct.

EDIT: Let me add on to exactly what I'm doing.

So I'm getting all the cookies in the browser using this function:

```
getAllCookies : function(){
  var pairs = document.cookie.split(";");
  var cookies = {};
  for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++){
    var pair = pairs[i].split("=");
    cookies[pair[0]] = unescape(pair[1]);
  }
  return cookies;
}
```

From that I get the object cookies.

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/unXsN/

Comment: @tymeJV you should post that as the answer and get some points ;)

Comment: @tymeJV I updated the question sorry.

Comment: Well if your `cookies` object looks like what you've posted, it'll still work.

Comment: Could you please do a `console.log(key)` at the item that returns `undefined`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are spaces in a cookie string, so you need to trim the name first, or just split with whitespace:

```
var pairs = document.cookie.split(/\s*;\s*/);
```

Comment: amazing! that was it :O